# unresolved overloaded function type with thread vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, overloading

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

//#define numEntries 100
class CAS
{
private:
std::vector <std::thread> threads;
long tagIndex,arg_tag;
public:

struct vtable
{
  long tag;
};

std::vector<vtable> vt;

CAS(int numEntries)
{
  vt.resize(numEntries);
}

void pSearch(int i)
{
 int a=10;

  //unsigned i= *((unsigned *)thInd);  

  //if(arg_tag==vt[i].tag)
  //tagIndex=i;
}

void CAS_threadEND(int i)
{
threads[i].join();
}

void parallelSearchINIT(unsigned numEntries, int _tag)
{
  //threads.resize(numEntries);
  for(unsigned i=0;i<numEntries;i++)
      {
    arg_tag=_tag;
    threads.push_back(std::thread (CAS::pSearch,i));



    // t;
    //(void (A::*)(int)) &A::pSearch

  }


}




};

int main()
{

int _tag=11;
unsigned numEntries=100;
CAS c(numEntries);
c.parallelSearchINIT(numEntries,_tag);

for(unsigned i=0;i<numEntries;i++)
c.CAS_threadEND(i);



}
```

I am receiving the following error at the thread creation line:

```
suryakalpo@suryakalpo-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~/Documents/gem5$ g++ -    std=c++11 -pthread cas1.cc
cas1.cc: In member function ‘void CAS::parallelSearchINIT(unsigned int, int)’:
cas1.cc:50:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, unsigned int&)’
threads.push_back(std::thread (CAS::pSearch,i));  
                                            ^
cas1.cc:50:48: note: candidates are:
In file included from cas1.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:133:7: note:      std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (CAS::*)(int); _Args = {unsigned int&}]
   thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:133:7: note:   no known conversion for   argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘void   (CAS::*&&)(int)’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:128:5: note:    std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
 thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
 ^
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:128:5: note:   candidate expects 1  argument, 2 provided
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:122:5: note: std::thread::thread()
 thread() noexcept = default;
 ^
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:122:5: note:   candidate expects 0    arguments, 2 provided
```

I tried to resolve the function overloading by casting the member function: `threads.push_back(std::thread ((void (CAS::*)(int)) &CAS::pSearch,i));`

But that did not resolve the overloading, instead I get this:

```
suryakalpo@suryakalpo-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~/Documents/gem5$ g++ - std=c++11 -pthread cas1.cc
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,
             from cas1.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct    std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (CAS::*)(int)>(unsigned int)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from   ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void   (CAS::*)(int); _Args = {unsigned int&}]’
cas1.cc:49:70:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’   in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (CAS::*)(int)>(unsigned int)>’
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’   in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (CAS::*)(int)>(unsigned int)>’
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

Can someone please tell me why is there a case of function overloading ? Because I honestly cannot determine the source of the overloading. Moreover, is it a case of overloading for the member function of class CAS or for the constructor of class thread ?

Comment: Please format your code to something readable.

Comment: Good idea to not show the code for `void CAS::parallelSearchINIT`. That'll leave them SO readers guessing. Yay! :)

Comment: [GCC 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d18e045c185838b) gives better errors (and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a37484af08add790) as well). Not the best considering your desired usage, but a bit more consistent with other errors of the same type from what I've seen.